# Use cut and grep to separate data while printing multiple fields

Tags: bash

I want to be able to separate data by weeks, and the week is stated in a specific field on every line and would like to know how to use grep, cut, or anything else that's relevant JUST on that field the week is specified in while still being able to save the rest of the data that's being given to me. I need to be able to pipe the information into it via | because that's how the rest of my program needs it to be.

as the output gets processed, it should look something like this

```
asset.14548.extension    0
asset.40795.extension    0
asset.98745.extension    1
```

I want to be able to sort those names by their week number while still being able to keep the asset name in my output because the number of times that asset shows up is counted up, but my problem is I can't make my program smart enough to take just the "1" from the week number but smart enough to ignore the "1" located in the asset name.

UPDATE

The closest answer I found was

```
grep "^.........................$week" ;
```

That's good, but it relies on every string being the same length. Is there a way I can have it start from the right instead of the left? Because if so then that'd answer my question.

^ tells grep to start checking from the left and . tells grep to ignore whatever's in that space

Comment: It's not clear what you're trying to do, sample input, current output and desired output would help.

Comment: i recommend you use `awk`/`gawk` for this instead of `grep` and `cut`.

Comment: "I'll try to be as straight forward as I can " .... we don't need all of that, sample input, expected output, current code, current output/error msgs. And agree that `[g]awk` is the way to go. Good clu,.

Comment: What I'm trying to do is check for a matching number in the week column while ignoring the rest of the text on the line without deleting the rest of the text from my output. As the information gets piped through different commands, it comes out looking like the piece with the asset name and the number next to it, and I need something that just checks that column for a specific number and returns every line that has that number in that column.

Comment: and where I'm stuck is if I use grep and check for 0, it'll look for 0 on the whole line instead of just that one spot I needed it to check, but I need the whole line in my output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found what I was looking for in some documentation. Anchor matches!

```
grep "$week$" file
```

would output this if $week was 0

```
asset.14548.extension    0
asset.40795.extension    0
```

I couldn't find my exact question or a closely similar question with a simple answer, so hopefully it helps the next person scratching their head on this.

Comment: `awk` is ideal for this type of operation, example: `$ awk '$NF~0{print}' file`